# FFMPEG - can you have comments in script files?

Tags: ffmpeg, scripting

Because of batch's poor ability to handle multi-line strings, I'm using FFMPEG script files more and more for `filter_complex` arguments.  I'm wondering if there is any way to include comments in these files.  They seem to be quite tolerant of white space and line breaks.  I've tried:

```
#
#   comment
#
```

and

```
;
;   comment
;
```

and

```
`
`   comment
`
```

and

```
'
'   comment
'
```

with no success.  It doesn't look as if comments are *officially* supported, but I'm wondering of there is some syntax quirk that allows them?

*** CLARIFICATION ***

I'm not talking about comments in batch files here, but comments in `filter_complex_script` files.  FFMPEG supports specifying the `filter_complex` argument string in a separate file.  So instead of:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v] crop=w=100:h=100:x=12:y=34 " "output.mp4"
```

you can specify:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -filter_complex_script "crop.txt" "output.mp4"
```

where crop.txt contains

```
[0:v] crop=w=100:h=100:x=12:y=34
```

This is really handy when the filter_complex string gets more complicated (I routinely deal with arguments 10,000 characters in length).

Comment: Never used ffmpeg, but according to the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-141), `#` should work.

Comment: Not actually sure what that documentation is referring to - probably bash script or something, but `#` isn't valid in a `filter_complex_script` file.

Comment: No comments accommodated in a `filter_complex_script`, I'm afraid. You could preprocess it though. Generate a script with comments on their own lines. Then pass the stripped version to ffmpeg.

Comment: Worth adding though, don't you think?  <smirk>

Comment: @rossmcm Sure. Consider submitting a [feature request](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/) (or a patch).

Answer (score 1):

You can use drawtext with an Y out of the image :-D

```
...
rotate=(t/4),

drawtext=text='This is a comment. OMG I am so smart!':y=1000,

crop=500:500:100:100,
...
```